# How To Check the Input from editText is integer in C++

Tags: c++, validation, android-edittext, integer

I want to validate the input from  Edit Text, if the input is not integer, Message Box or Show Message will appear, i use

```
if(input->Text.ToIntDef(1)){
  //instruction
}
```

but when i run the app, `if` condition always `true`, even though i input integer in the Edit Text(i input 5000, 4500, 7000, 7500, 2000, 2500)

Comment: Night? It's day time here. (hint: this is a global site and greetings are considered noise that are not relevant to the question)

Comment: My guess is that `ToIntDef` converts the value in `Text` to an integer, and if it is not an integer it will return `1`. Since your are checking the integer value the function returns, the only way it can be false, is if you enter the integer `0`. This does not seem like a reliable way of doing this, unless you really do not want people to enter `0`.

Comment: so, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method, could be to scan the content of the string, if you detect anything that is not a digit, you can stop the scan and assume that the number is not an integer.

```
bool is_integer(const char* input) {
    while(*input) {
        if (*input < '0' ||  *input > '9') {
            return false;
        }
        ++input;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The simple approach above considers an empty string an integer as well, it is a simple matter to change that. Further more any white space in the input will cause the function to treat the input as not being an integer, if you want white spaces to be ignored, you can trim the input before passing it to the function.

From your example I get a suspicion that you are using the VCL-like framework: FireMonkey from C++ Builder, this framework has a method on its default string class called [`ToInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.UnicodeString.ToInt) as far as I recall (without the `Def` suffix) which will attempt to parse the string as an integer, if unable to, it will throw an `EConvertError` exception, which you can then basically just catch.